# Does Google Chrome Web Audio API implementation support ScriptProcessorNode.bufferSize zero (auto)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-audio, web-audio-api

The Web Audio API spec states that the ScriptProcessorNode.bufferSize property value ["will be picked by the implementation if the bufferSize argument to createScriptProcessor is not passed in, or is set to 0"](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#ScriptProcessorNode).

Elsewhere is states that ["It is recommended for authors to not specify this buffer size and allow the implementation to pick a good buffer size to balance between latency and audio quality."](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#methodsandparams-AudioContext) when calling `createScriptProcessor()`.

However, when I use either a value of zero or call `createJavaScriptNode()` without the `bufferSize` argument an error is thrown in the Developement console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified.

This error is erroneous, I've verified that the argument is a number, not a string.

However the `createScriptProcessor()` result fails and the debugger will stop on the line that calls `createScriptProcessor()` if you set it to *'Pause on uncaught exceptions'*.

It seems to me Chrome doesn't support the `auto` value and the `bufferSize` value must be set explicitly to one of these values:

```
256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384.
```

- Does anyone have any experience with this?
- Does Google Chrome have a `ScriptProcessorNode.bufferSize` automatic implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's a new(ish) addition to the draft.

Chrome (stable) just hasn't caught up yet. But the change has already made its way into Chrome Canary. With no arg or an arg of `0`, it'll set a default `bufferSize`. On my machine (maybe all machines?) it's `512`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, good to know that Canary supports the spec. You're correct, after a bit more research, looks like the language that describes the auto/zero bufferSize value was published in the recent October 10, 2013 spec. The previously published version from December of 2012 didn't have this behavior specified. I suppose I'll stub out my code for future support and implement a mandatory valid value for now.